# Why aren't my functions doing what I tell them to in ursina python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, game-development, ursina

The function 'aimshot()' plays a sound and an animation in a certain spot (when aiming) and the same with the function 'noaimshot()' but when not aiming. For some reason, when I try to run these functions later in the 'def input(key)' function they do not work.

```
def aimshot():
        Audio("assets/GunShot.mp3")
        Animation("assets/spark", parent=camera.ui, fps=5, scale=.1, position=(.00, -.726), loop=False)

def noaimshot():
    Audio("assets/GunShot.mp3")
    Animation("assets/spark", parent=camera.ui, fps=5, scale=.1, position=(.34, -.54), loop=False)

def input(key):
    if key == 'escape':
        quit()

    if key == "q":
        aim.enable()
        noaim.disable()
        if key == "left mouse down":
           noaimshot()


    if key == "e":
        aim.disable()
        noaim.enable()
        if key == "left mouse down":
            aimshot()
```

The full code is here. NOTE: you will need to pip install ursina to run this.

```
from ursina import *
from random import uniform
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
Sky()
player=FirstPersonController(y=10, origin_y=1)
ground=Entity(model='plane', scale=(20, 1, 20), color=color.lime, texture="white_cube",
              texture_scale=(20, 20), collider='box')


noaim = Entity(model="assets/gun.obj", parent=camera.ui, scale=.03, color=rgb(0, 0, 139), position=(.5, -.7),
            rotation=(-5, 5, 1))

aim = Entity(model="assets/gun.obj", parent=camera.ui, scale=.03, color=rgb(0, 0, 139), position=(.00, -.726),
                     rotation=(-5, 1, -1))
aim.disable()


def aimshot():
        Audio("assets/GunShot.mp3")
        Animation("assets/spark", parent=camera.ui, fps=5, scale=.1, position=(.00, -.726), loop=False)

def noaimshot():
    Audio("assets/GunShot.mp3")
    Animation("assets/spark", parent=camera.ui, fps=5, scale=.1, position=(.34, -.54), loop=False)

def input(key):
    if key == 'escape':
        quit()

    if key == "q":
        aim.enable()
        noaim.disable()
        if key == "left mouse down":
           noaimshot()


    if key == "e":
        aim.disable()
        noaim.enable()
        if key == "left mouse down":
            aimshot()

app.run()
```

Comment: As an aside, the word is just "function", not "defined functions".

Comment: In any case, you **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you save the Audio object in a variable and then use `gunshot.play()`?

Comment: what is you error and what do you really wanted to do?

Comment: remember you have to hold **q** button and click the left mouse button.

Comment: @Tanay there is no direct error but I want to make it so when I am aimed in (or i have clicked q) when i click left mouse button, my sound is played and it shows the animation in a different spot then when im not aimed in (clicked e)

Comment: It is impossible for `key == "left mouse down"` to be true inside a `if key == "q":` block...

Comment: @jasonharper Ok thank you for letting me know. Do you know of any way I could get the same result a different way?

Comment: @QstzD you can set animation's `position` to `mouse.position`

Comment: @Tanay that will only work for when I am aimed in tho. Ursina sets your mouse position at one spot for the whole thing so when i aim in (via the Q key) my mouse doesnt follow.

Comment: naming a function `input` is not a good idea. what if you want some input from the user? the python builtin input function will not be accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Because the if statement is never True, so the code below never runs. You can check the state of variable by printing it, for example `print(key)`.

The variable `key` can't be both "q" and "left mouse down" at the same time.
If you want to check if "q" is being held down at the point you press "left mouse down", you could do:

```py
if held_keys["q"] and key == "left mouse down":
    noaimshot()
```

Answer (score -2):

[image: look at this]

this is the reason why your code is not working, you can't define a function with 2 tabs but with only one

Comment: That is simply incorrect. Indentation must be consistent in the same function, but separate functions can be indented with a different amount of whitespace.